# C# Process with SQLite3 and cmd.exe

Tags: c#, sqlite, cmd

I am trying to run cmd.exe through C# app in order to use the sqlite3 commands. I cannot figure out why it is not working correctly. Maybe there is an alternative?

My attempts at solution was to first utilize `using System.Data.SQLite;` Turns out this library does not contain sqlite3 shell functions. So this is not an option. Additionally I tried calling sqlite3.exe independently but again this does not allow for certain commands that I require from cmd.

```
Process SQLp = new Process();
SQLp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
SQLp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
SQLp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
SQLp.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:/temp"; //Contains sqlite3.exe
SQLp.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
SQLp.Start();
StreamWriter SQLStreamWriter = SQLp.StandardInput;

inputText = "sqlite3 databasename";
SQLStreamWriter.WriteLine(inputText);
string output = SQLp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
textBox1.Text = output;
SQLp.WaitForExit();
```

Manually entering "sqlite3 databasename" in cmd does not give the same output as above. In fact it appears it is ignored. My end goal is to be able to give commands such as the one above and .read abc.sql, .import xyz.csv etc.

Comment: Did you tried with sqlitestudio? 
What kind of commands do you have to execute, that are not executable with sqlite.exe? Can you give an example?

Comment: sqlitestudio did the trick. Thanks

Comment: `sqlite3` is its own command line, so you wouldn't need to wrap it with `cmd.exe`. Also _databasename_ would then go into the `Arguments` property of the `ProcessStartInfo`